# Ubuntu on a USB stick - mount options to reduce writes

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, ext4, fat32

I'd like to have Ubuntu installed on a USB stick, that I could plug in (almost) any computer and boot from it, and that I could use (almost) normally, as if it was installed on that computer. I'd also like to have a data partition on it that could be used by (almost) any computer, mostly to store some portable apps, just in case.

---

My main concern is to increase the lifetime of my drive, but without making it too unstable.

To do that, I have to choose the right options in `/etc/fstab` for my partitions.
Currently, I'm thinking about these:

- `/`: ext4, `defaults,lazytime,commit=60,errors=remount-ro`
- `/media/data`: FAT32, `defaults,lazytime,check=strict`

So `lazytime` should be better than the often proposed `noatime` or the default `relatime`, since, as I understand it, it's applied to creation, access and modification times, it's POSIX compliant (contrary to `relatime`), and it reduces the amount of write cycles by storing times in RAM and writing them from time to time.

Combined with `commit=60`, it should reduce writes enough to compensate the journal of ext4, that I want to keep to have a stable system.

Do you think those options are good enough?
Do you see other options I could use to reduce writes but keep a stable system?

---

My current setup:

- USB stick: [SanDisk Ultra Fit (32 Go)](http://usb.userbenchmark.com/SanDisk-Ultra-Fit-USB-30-32GB/Rating/2697)
- OS: Xubuntu 16.04 i386
- installation: full install (from a Live USB built with Rufus)
- drivers: none proprietary
- file systems:

  - partition table: [GPT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873004)

    - 2: [ESP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873004), `/boot/efi`, 128 Mio, FAT32, [boot,esp]
    - 3: [ABP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873004), 128 Mio, HFS+
    - 4: [BBP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873004), 2 Mio, [bios_grub]
    - 5: swap, 512 Mio
    - 6: [root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870638), `/`, 24 Gio, ext4, `defaults,errors=remount-ro,lazytime,commit=60`
    - 1: [data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870638), `/media/data`, ~3.6 Gio, FAT32, `defaults,lazytime,check=strict`
  - RAM:

    - `/tmp`, tmpfs, `defaults,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777`
- swap:

  - `vm.swappiness=5`
  - swap partition: 512 Mio, for emergency
  - zRAM
  - swap files:

    - `/var/swap/hib.swp`: same size as RAM, for hibernation, generated by a script at startup
    - `/var/swap/opt.swp`: if needed, generated by a script
- overprovisioning: ~5.6%

  - built-in: ~1.2 Gio (apparently)
  - added: 512 Mio
- scheduler: `deadline`

Comment: `lazytime` is independent and can be combined with `noatime` / `relatime` see here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276863/209113

Comment: Yes but I'd like to use the original (and POSIX) `atime` if possible, if `lazytime` reduces writes enough.

Comment: OK, that's a game changer, i usually don't need `atime` at all. I use with no problems `noatime` with `lazytime`, `ZRAM` / `ZSWAP`, and higher _commit_ values such _90-180s_ _(even 600s)_. All of course depending on your system requeriments.

Comment: Do you mean you use ZRAM and ZSWAP at the same time? I hope so because I was thinking about using ZRAM and didn't know about ZWAP, and now I'd hate to have to choose…

Comment: No only one is recomended, check this for more info http://askubuntu.com/a/472227/298047 _(but yes you'll have to choose...)_. For your use case I would go with `ZRAM` to avoid _almost any_ hdd(usb)-swapping _(it's used on default Lubuntu installer)_. Also check @sudodus answer, who has wide knowledge about this kind of things.

Comment: Well ok… Yes ZRAM makes sense since I only use an emergency swap partition. And yes it's one of his posts that made me discover ZRAM ^^

Comment: And what do you think about `swapspace` ?

Comment: Mostly OK, maybe I would set somehow higher swappiness value, maybe arround _20_ (but with ZRAM it is uncommon your system reach to swapping). Also I don't like hibernation to much.

Comment: No I mean the tool called `swapspace`, its supposed do dynamically generate swap files. But I'm also interested in your opinion about my swap setup ^^ You mean you would make it swap more often?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51838/discussion-between-dgonzalez-and-cidtori).

Comment: @CidTori can you give an update on all the options you used, did it all work well?

Comment: I’d like to, but I had to stop working on that project a long time ago  I didn’t encounter new problems anyway, and I’m interested in any feedback if someone wants to try it

Comment: If I remember well, I did try configuring everything as in my questions, except the swap part I think, without problem, but I can’t say if the writes reduction was really effective 

Answer (score 5):

I have made a lot of installed systems into USB flash drives, and I think such systems can work quite well. You have found some mount options, that I have not found (and not used). I am looking forward to future reports from you :-)

---

See this link about my systems, and the tweaks that I suggest,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS#Final_system_tweaks](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS#Final_system_tweaks)

I think it is important to get a fast USB 3 flash drive (and I think there are better drives for this purpose than the Ultra Fit),

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed)

I think that the lifetime of good USB pendrives is rather good now, but still, it is important to **backup** all important files at regular intervals.

---

An alternative is a **persistent live drive** with a *casper-rw* partiiton, and if you wish you can add a *home-rw* partition,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

A persistent live drive is more portable, but cannot be updated and upgraded like an installed system (the kernel and drivers cannot be upgraded). But an installed system is often portable enough.

Comment: Yes I saw those pages when searching about this =) I know that Ultra Fit does not fit well for this, but it's really cheap so it's perfect to test things out ^^ I saw a lot of things about persistent Live USB, but since I want to be able to update and upgrade, I can't use it. Thanks for the feedback ! =)

Comment: When following your first link, I found [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2213631&p=13262506#post13262506). After the installation, you tweak `/syslinux/txt.cfg` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Why is that needed? And should I worry about UEFI and BIOS?

Comment: That post is describing a special system, where `/syslinux/txt.cfg` is tweaked to add a menu entry for the installed system. You need not worry about UEFI and BIOS, but if you want to use the pendrive to boot an installed system in computers running in UEFI mode and computers running in BIOS mode, and not only one of those boot modes, you need a special procedure after the basic installation.

Comment: Well, I'm interested… I think it will be my next question ^^

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/258753/how-to-make-ubuntu-use-more-ram-to-cache-a-specific-set-of-binaries