# 16.04: USB formatting interrupted - not seen in diskmgmt or lsblk

Tags: usb, usb-drive, fdisk, vmware-player

Previously working device in freshly-made VMware VM of 16.04 x64 on  Win 8.1 x64 guest.

While following the top answer in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873004/ubuntu-on-a-usb-stick-boot-in-both-bios-and-uefi-modes), I was interrupted before I got a chance to write the changes and shutdown the computer.  Upon reboot the device can be seen in Windows, but not in the VM.  I did all sorts of reboots, unplugs, and even remade the VM and still can't get the device to be recognized in Ubuntu.  Any thoughts or troubleshooting steps I can try?

Here is the snipped output of `dmesg -wH`:

```
    [Apr 2 02:25] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
    [  +0.025088] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=1a0e
    [  +0.000009] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
    [  +0.000005] usb 4-1: Product: Voyager GTX
    [  +0.000005] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Corsair
    [  +0.000004] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 511140731034000036
    [  +0.096169] scsi host33: uas
    [  +0.012696] usb 4-1: stat urb: status -32
    [  +0.000114] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 data cmplt err -32 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
    [  +0.000010] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Inquiry 12 00 00 00 24 00
    [Apr 2 02:26] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
    [  +0.000008] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Inquiry 12 00 00 00 24 00
    [  +0.000188] scsi host33: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
    [  +0.123851] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
    [  +0.130123] scsi host33: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
    [  +0.002031] usb 4-1: stat urb: status -32
    [  +0.003326] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
    [  +0.000010] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
    [  +0.000008] scsi host33: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
    [  +0.228541] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
    [  +0.216271] scsi host33: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
    [  +0.000012] scsi 33:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
```

Here is the snipped output from `lsusb -v`:

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1b1c:1a0e Corsair 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1b1c Corsair
  idProduct          0x1a0e 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2 
  iProduct                3 
  iSerial                 1 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          121
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              224mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     98 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
        MaxStreams             32
        Data-in pipe (0x03)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
        MaxStreams             32
        Data-out pipe (0x04)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
        MaxStreams             32
        Status pipe (0x02)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
        Command pipe (0x01)
```