# Installing Ubuntu OS on Pen Drive (not creating Live USB)

Tags: usb

When installing Ubuntu 19.04 64 bit onto a 32GB USB 3.0 pendrive.
I went into the "Something Else" section and created 2 partitions.
my Pendrive came under "sdc".
Partition 1: type EFI System Partition. 1024MB.
Partition 2: type EXT4 with mounting point '/' (without quotes). Atleast 32GB.
The install completes with no errors.

Usually at this point i have to enter the bios of my laptop and "register" the efi files so that i can boot into the Ubuntu on the Pendrive.

when i select USB0 it opens up empty. (normally it should a folder "Ubuntu" which would contain grub, shim and 2 more files)

I have tried this several times.
But i guess that for some reason the EFI files are not being installed on the ESP partition at all.

any ideas why this is happening or im i doing something wrong.

PS
if i disconnect all internal drives and install via the "install ubuntu 19.04" (the first option). it install everything perfectly efi files included.

Comment: Full install USB UEFI and BIOS - https://askubuntu.com/questions/873004/ubuntu-on-a-usb-stick-boot-in-both-bios-and-uefi-modes/1118412#1118412

Comment: Ubuntu installer only installs grub .efi boot files to first ESP - efi system partition it sees, usually sda or first NVMe drive. But you can manually copy /EFI/ubuntu twice to ESP on flash drive, once to /EFI/ubuntu and once to /EFI/Boot. You may now be able to just copy /EFI/Boot as now grub does create a /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. USB drives only boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, but grub needs to see /EFI/ubuntu folder. You then need to edit fstab to use correct ESP for updates. Boot-Repair may also allow you to force a reinstall of grub to USB flash drive when you boot from internal drive..

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to
wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug.
There are workarounds/solutions in the bug comments. Another problem is
that your host system probably will not boot without the external device (since
needed grub files are on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fix needed after the install. Ubuntu will likely install the boot files on your PC's EFI partition, even if you selected the USB device. The fix is to copy/move that boot files from the PC's EFI partitions to the USB's EFI partition.

After a long research, I discovered a simple procedure that produces full&portable Ubuntu 19.04 installations on USB drive - even when installing from a Win10 PC.

The resulting Linux on USB can boot on most compatible CPUs. You can customize this Linux, you can update it - like you do with any native Linux install. It even booted on a Mac, however I had to use keyboard, mouse and network on USB.

https://meaningofstuff.blogspot.com/2019/09/linux-ubuntu-1904-full-install-on-usb.html