# Could I switch computers with my Ubuntu installation on an external hard drive?

Tags: drivers, system-installation, compatibility, cpu-architecture

I installed Ubuntu 18.04, then upgraded to 20.04, on an external USB SSD drive for use with my laptop.

I am getting a new computer (desktop) and want to start using the same SSD with that. Could I just switch computers without any groundwork?

Could the existing drivers on my installation crash my new computer? Is there anything else I should be aware of?

My laptop has an AMD A10 processor and built in AMD R graphics.

The desktop will be AMD Ryzen 5 and Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your EFI bootable partition is probably on your internal drive, that might make the external not read as a boot drive on new computer.  Besides that as long as everything is updated, it should work.  New drivers will need to be installed to work well.  See this link for more ideas.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196394/can-i-boot-an-external-ssd-with-ubuntu-18-04-installed-on-any-computer?rq=1

Comment: @crip659 Thank you for replying, that is helpful advice. I will look at that link and read through the answers for any insight. I'm not sure where the bootable partition is. I see a blue screen asking me to choose between Windows and Ubuntu. Then the standard Linux boot screen for picking how to boot.

Comment: For a GUI, use your 'disks' program to see all your partitions on all drives.  EFI partition be around 300MBs, give or take 200MBs(should be smallest).  Your Ubuntu should be on sdb drive.  Internal should be sda and have more partitions, but depends on your setup.

Comment: You should be OK as long as both computers boot in the same BIOS/UEFI mode. If you are dual booting Windows, it should also boot in the same mode as Ubuntu for GRUB to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux builds the device structure every time it boots so yes, that will work.

The only thing to do is to remove 3rd party drivers and generally those are the display and the wireless driver if you have different hardware. Please do make sure you have a wired connection to the internet to be able to download and install those drivers.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The information you provided is very helpful. I will keep these things in mind when making the switch. Not knowing where to go with this was troubling. I just wasn't sure about one thing. Should I remove the 3rd party drivers before or after making the switch? And how would I remove the old and add the new drivers? Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully Ubuntu will find new drivers after switch, but might need to search google for ubuntu black screen till finding new drivers.  New drivers after new hardware.

Comment: @StackMatch before you take the ssd out remove the 3rd party drivers.

Comment: How can it prompt you for network login credentials before it has updated itself to use drivers matching the new machine's network adapter and display? where's the magic? does it have most necessary drivers on file so that it doesn't need the network for updating to the new hardware?

Comment: @matanster Linux in general has support in the kernel for anything generic. Graphics cards work with opensource drivers. NICs too. (but there are expeptions). Less and less you need to plug in an utp cable to connect so you can d/l a nic driver.