# Why do I loose storage space with persistent usb stick?

Tags: live-usb, 19.10, storage, persistence, rufus

I've been testing >4Gb persistent live-usb with ubuntu 19.10 + rufus on a 32 Gb usb stick but somehow I ran out of space as soon as I upgraded to get full functionality.

So I bought a 128 Gb usb stick and did it all over again (I'm writing on this persistent ubuntu right now).
I specified maximum aviable persistent storage (about 117 Gb if I remember correctly) on rufus, but somehow the Disk Usage Utility tells me I've got only 31 Gb of free space ! And I haven't upgraded yet !

[image: Here is the screenshot of the Disk Usage Utility window]

So, 31 should be enough to get my OS upgraded and install full LaTeX support but still, I'd like the ~90 missing Gbs to be usable.

Any idea ?

Comment: You get best disk utilization by doing a Full install to USB. For BIOS boot see https://www.ncf.ca/ncf/support/wiki/Puppy_Linux , for UEFI / BIOS boot see https://askubuntu.com/questions/873004/ubuntu-on-a-usb-stick-boot-in-both-bios-and-uefi-modes/1118412#1118412 . Both methods allow optional NTFS or FAT data partition for  use by Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rufus developer here.

Please be very mindful that persistent storage in Rufus is still flagged as **EXPERIMENTAL** (it was only added very recently, and both the web site and the Changelog try to make it clear that this is an experimental feature), which means that there might be some elements that need to be finalized and bugs that need to be fixed.

Especially, we seem to have an [issue](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/1396) where the amount of free space seems to decrease a lot more than it should when writing data, similar to what you described above.

We are trying to find the time to fix this, but this seems to be a complex issue, that requires us to become very familiar with the intrinsics of the `ext2/ext3` file systems, so it is likely to take a bit longer before we can do so.

In the meantime, we advise you to run `e2fsck` on the persistent partition and be mindful that features that are flagged **EXPERIMENTAL** may not be entirely finalized yet.

Comment: Hey Akeo, thanks for the explanation, I'll go with Cameron's process for now but I'm eager to see Rufus able to do it :-) All the best !