# Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS on a USB key boot problem

Tags: server, usb, bios

We need to install Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS on a USB key for a backup solution in case our main drive fails over a given period of time. So, basically, the USB key is formatted as FAT32 with MBR boot option. When we boot the Ubuntu Server installation on a second USB key, we can format and install the OS on the USB without any issues (automatic partitioning using LVM).

But, as soon as the installation is finished and the system reboots we're getting an error saying that there is no bootable device found. For that matter, if we press F10 at boot, we can select the USB Ubuntu Server installation and it boots without any issues. But we're using Intel NUC that doesn't have any keyboard (kiosk mode) so we can't press F10 at boot.

We are using Legacy BIOS and can't change any BIOS settings since our Intel NUCS are deployed in the field and the clients don't have access to this option for security matters.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is not about Ubuntu, but about the computer's BIOS settings. - What happens if you (or the end users) remove the internal drive? If you are lucky(?), the system might find the backup solution (the USB drive with Ubuntu Server) and boot from it. Otherwise you may need to provide the  backup solution on the same kind of drive as the internal system (and let the end users replace the internal drive when necessary).

Comment: We unplugged the internal SSD to simulate a failure and we're getting the same error message: "No boot device found". Our users aren't tech savvy and it would be difficult for them to replace the SSD with a new one. So, we thought that the USB solution would be an easier fix for them in case the SSD fail.

Comment: It is a problem that you want to protect from booting from USB and at the same time want to boot the backup solution from USB. I think you would have to modify the BIOS to allow booting from USB in order for this solution to work.

Comment: There is a checkbox on the BIOS that says Boot USB device first which is checked. The USB thumb drive with the Ubuntu installer boots directly without pressing F10. So, the BIOS settings should be fine.

Comment: That's promising :-) So maybe it will be enough to add some boot flag to the USB drive with the backup solution (with Ubuntu Server).

Comment: Already did with GParted on the boot partition.

Comment: If nothing else works, maybe a solution according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873004/ubuntu-on-a-usb-stick-boot-in-both-bios-and-uefi-modes/1118412#1118412) may work.

Comment: It seems that I need to format the USB drive like this: 1st partition to FAT32 with the grub_bios boot flag to be set since I can't use EFI mode. The remaining partition as ext4 should be formatted with ext4 and Ubuntu server installed on it. And Grub need to be installed in the first partition with the correct boot flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105445/discussion-between-sudodus-and-nicolas-boulet-lavoie).